# How to read the selected item's value of a html dropdown menu in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in html that contains a drop down menu like so

```
<form name= "gadget_selector">
    <select name= "gadget">
        <option value = 0> Something </option>
        <option value = 1> Something else </option>
        //etc..
    </select> 
</form>
```

And I want to access the value of the selected option in a javascript function like so

```
function someFunction(){

    //var option = value of selected menu option
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 15):

```
var option = document.getElementById('gadget').value;
```

Set `gadget` as the `id` for the select as well, like this:

```
<select id="gadget" name="gadget">
        <option value = 0> Something </option>
        <option value = 1> Something else </option>
        //etc..
    </select>
```

Comment: Is `val()` in vanilla javascript? I thought it belongs to jQuery.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work, `.val()` is not a native function for any browser. you're looking for `.value` rather than `.val()`

Comment: ah, yes. my bad. Been using jquery too much

Answer (score 2):

assign `id` to `select box` "gadget":

```
   <select name= "gadget" id="gadget">
    <option value = 0> Something </option>
        <option value = 1> Something else </option>
        //etc..
    </select>
```

Now get selected value in javascript like below :

```
function GetSelectedItem() {

     var option = document.getElementById('gadget').value;

    }
```

Comment: I tried to do a test

     var option = document.getElementById('gadget').val();
     alert(option);

Still no go though. The first post didn't quite work either

Comment: @Zack: I checked it working ok with  document.getElementById('gadget').value for me. So check your all html tags or javascript error in console. even try with simple javascript alert if that working or not. Might be Something other is conflicting

Answer (score 2):

Include an `id` `attribute` to select element and do as below, i am sure i will work,

```
var obj = document.getElementById("gadget");
alert(obj.value); // returns selected option value   (1st method)
var selectedOption = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex]; // returns selected option element
alert(selectedOption.value); // return selected option value (2nd method)
```

example : http://jsfiddle.net/zUBpz/

Answer (score 0):

First, assign an id to your `<select>` tag.

```
<select id='gadget' name= "gadget">
```

Then, get its value

```
if (document.getElementById('gadget')) {
  var val = document.getElementById('gadget').value;
  alert(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access by id, like this:=

```
    <form name= "gadget_selector" >
        <select name= "gadget" id='sel'>
            <option value = 0> Something </option>
            <option value = 1> Something else </option>
            //etc..
        </select> 
    </form> 


    function getvalue(){

       if(document.getElementById('sel'))
       {
         alert(document.getElementById('sel').value);
         var option = document.getElementById('sel').value;
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here forms[0] is the form number starting from 0 from top to bottom of page

```
function someFunction(){
    var option = window.document.forms[0].gadget.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but maybe other people get here like me so I'll add my solution:

The cleanest approach would be to have a reference to the `select` field, have the `select` backed by a model and add a watcher like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',

  data() {
    return {
      myValueName: 123
    };
  },

  watch: {
    myValueName() {
      //
      // Will log "Value: 123" and "Value: 456" instead of 
      // "123" and "456".
      //
      console.log(this.$refs['mySelectRef'].selectedOptions[0].text);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <select ref="mySelectRef" v-model="myValueName">
    <option :value="123">Value: 123</option>
    <option :value="456">Value: 456</option>
  </select>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```